# How to add label to one particular arrangedSubView of a UIStackView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uistackview

I have below code in swift for the "ViewController" 
class ViewController: UIViewController ,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

```
@IBOutlet weak var imgTableView:UITableView!

let imgList = ["1.png", "2.png", "3.png" , "4.png"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.imgList.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellID", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? ImgTableViewCell

    cell?.coverImage.image = UIImage(named: imgList[0])

    for intValue in 1..<4
    {
        let stackViewImages = UIImageView()
        stackViewImages.image = UIImage(named: imgList[intValue])
        cell?.imgStackView.addArrangedSubview(stackViewImages)
    }

    return cell!

}
```

}

+++++++++++++++++++++++

class ImgTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

```
@IBOutlet weak var coverImage:UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var imgStackView:UIStackView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

}

How do I add label to the last photo in the stackview. I have tried creating a new label and add it programmatically in the stackview by calling addsubview on the imageview inside the stackview but the label gets placed at the very top of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Since your UIStackView contains 4 UIImageView. You can use the index property of UIStackView to access object inside it. 
The way you insert object in StackView **-insertArrangedSubView :atIndex**

StackView index starts from 0 as other container object in Objective C.

You create a pointer to you image view inside stack view like this:

**UIImageView *lastImageView = [stackView.subviews objectAtIndex:3];**

You can access it like this.

**lastImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];**

Now adding any other subview e.g.. *UILabel*, suppose your label name is *titleTextLabel,* than

**[lastImageView addSubview:self.titleTextLabel];**

Answer (score 0):

You have two possible ways to achieve that (btw, I encourage you to streamline your code as I did):
1) simply add you label as the last stack view view as follows:

```
if let sv = cell?.imgStackView {

    for i in 1..<4 {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv = UIImage(named: imgList[i])
        sv.addArrangedSubview(iv)
    }

    let l = UILabel()
    l.text = "the last image"
    l.frame.size.width = cell?.imgStackView.frame.width
    l.numberOfLines = 0
    l.sizeToFit()
    sv.addArrangedSubview(t)
}
```

2) or if you need to have the label in the same stack view cell than the last image, use constraint to position it where you want as follow, assuming you want the label beneath the image view :

```
if let sv = cell?.imgStackView {
    let n = 3
    for i in 1...n {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv = UIImage(named: imgList[i])
        sv.addArrangedSubview(iv)

        // last image: add a label underneath the image view
        if i == n {
            let l = UILabel()
            l.text = "the last image"
            l.frame.size.width = cell?.imgStackView.frame.width
            l.numberOfLines = 0
            l.sizeToFit()
            // Add the bottom-top constraint
            iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            iv.addConstraints([
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: l, attribute: .Top,   relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: iv, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
            ])
        }
    }
}
```

Hope out helps (btw, I did not compile my code in Xcode).